# how do you start opencpu service on SUSE

Tags: linux, r, opencpu

I installed opencpu on suse version 11. When i do this command from the R console:

```
library(opencpu)
```

Opencpu starts for single user, I can check the test page.

However, I actually need to install opencpu on a server, where multiple people can access. i only see Ubuntu and Debian installs. Has anybody done opencpu install on any other OS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have successfully installed OpenCPU server on a CentOS 6 using [Jeroen's instructions](https://github.com/jeroenooms/opencpu-server/blob/master/rpm/buildscript.sh) and have the same question. The init.d script provided for Ubuntu does not help me much.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This question was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706178/how-to-start-stop-flush-opencpu-on-centos6) and is applicable to SUSE.